# Activating Pinball bumper pentalties when points reaches a certain number

Tags: python

So I created a pinball script with two settings, which are the easy setting (Easy_Pinball) and the hard setting (Hard_Pinball). The Hard setting inherits all of the easy settings methods. The only difference is the hard setting has two methods which you can lose points. My question is, how can I "activate" the two methods in the Hard_Pinball class when the players points reaches 5 or above? Please note, I do not want these methods two go away once they have been activated. For example, someone hits five points on the pinball game, which then activates the Hard_Pinball methods, but then his points drop to 4, both methods in the hard setting should still work all the way down to zero, which would cause the player to lose the game. For some reason I'm stumped on this. Any help?

```
from random import randint

class Easy_Pinball(object):

    def __init__(self, points = 0, balls = 3):
        self.points = points
        self.balls = balls

#  When you hit this bumper, you get random number from 1 3


    def first_bumper(self, winner = 20):
        if self.points < winner:
            self.points += randint(1,3)
            if self.points >= winner:
                print('you win')
        elif self.points >= winner:
            print ('you win')

#  when you hit this bumper, you get random number from 3 6

    def second_bumper(self, winner = 20):
        if self.points < winner:
            self.points += randint(4,6)
            if self.points >= winner:
                print('you win')
        elif self.points >= winner:
            print('you win')

#  If you ball falls in hole, you lose one ball

     def losing_balls(self, lost_one = 1):
        if self.balls > 0:
            self.balls -= lost_one
        elif self.balls == 0:
            print('you lose, braaahh')




class Hard_Pinball(Easy_Pinball): 

#  activate bumpers where you can lose points when
#  your points total reaches 5

    def third_bumper(self, bumper = 1):
        if self.points > 0:
            self.points -= bumper
        elif self.points <= 0:
            print('you lose, you bum')

    def fourth_bumper(self, bumper = 5):
        if self.points > 0:
            self.points -= bumper
            if self.points <= 0:
                print('you lose, you bum')
        elif self.points <= 0:
            print('you lose, you bum')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use just a single `Pinball` class, and have a `difficulty` enum property that changes to `Difficulty.hard` when `points` reaches 5. Then, all calls to `third_bumper` and `fourth_bumper` can initially check if `self.difficulty == Difficulty.hard` before applying their respective point penalty.

I have also taken the liberty of simplifying some of your game logic using `@property` on the `points` and `balls` properties to trigger winning, losing, and difficulty adjustment automatically (meaning that logic is no longer spread out between your other methods).

```
from random import randint
from enum import Enum

class Difficulty(Enum):
    easy = 'easy'
    hard = 'hard'

class Pinball(object):

    def __init__(self, points = 0, balls = 3, winning_score = 20, hard_threshold = 5):
        self.winning_score = winning_score
        self.hard_threshold = hard_threshold
        self.difficulty = Difficulty.easy

        self.points = points
        self.balls = balls

    @property
    def points(self):
        return self._points

    @points.setter
    def points(self, v):
        self._points = v
        if v >= self.hard_threshold:
            self.difficulty = Difficulty.hard
        if v >= self.winning_score:
            self.win()

    @property
    def balls(self):
        return self._balls

    @balls.setter
    def balls(self, v):
        self._balls = v
        if v == 0:
            self.lose()

    def win(self):
        print('You win!')

    def lose(self):
        print('You lose!')

    #  When you hit this bumper, you get random number from 1 3

    def first_bumper(self):
        self.points += randint(1, 3)

    #  when you hit this bumper, you get random number from 3 6

    def second_bumper(self):
        self.points += randint(4, 6)

    #  If you ball falls in hole, you lose one ball

    def losing_balls(self, count = 1):
         self.balls -= count

    #  activate bumpers where you can lose points when
    #  your points total reaches 5

    def third_bumper(self, penalty = 1):
        if self.difficulty == Difficulty.hard:
            self.points -= penalty

    def fourth_bumper(self, penalty = 5):
        if self.difficulty == Difficulty.hard:
            self.points -= penalty
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any reason you are creating two variables under an enum class as opposed to just creating those two class variables under the Pinball class?

Comment: If you end up adding other difficulties, like `Difficulty.epic` or `Difficulty.tutorial`, it is much easier to manage the changes if you are using Enum constants.

Comment: Thanks man, one last question. I'm really not familiar with the enum modules or Enum class. Is there any reason you are using this class, as the code works perfectly fine without using Enum?

Comment: Just maintainability. No reason why you couldn't just use strings instead, if you prefer.